# How to include a django html template in a div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-templates

I would like to include a django html template in another template inside a div tag, like so:

```
{% block content %}
    <div id='content'>
        {% include 'template_to_include.html' %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Without the div I got the expected result but when I put the include tag inside the div, I got a blank line.
Any help is apreciated please

Here is the tree. My two files (template_to_include and template) are in the last folder (visualisation) inside the templates folder

```
templates
└── visualization
    ├── index-visualization.html
    └── visualization.html
```

Comment: Can you share the filetree where your templates are stored, together with the *parent* template that you extend.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using jinja2, so you can use {% extends "template_to_include.html" %}

Comment: jinja2 also has `include`, see: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#include the `include` and `extends` tag are two _different_ things...